# Converting Stream<Stream<T>> to List<T>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java 8. I have written following piece of code:

```
Stream<Stream<POLine>> list = poSearchResponseList.stream().map(poSearchResponse ->
        poSearchResponse.getDeliveryDocumentLines().stream().map(deliveryDocumentLine ->
                POLine.builder()
                        .poLineNumber(deliveryDocumentLine.getPurchaseReferenceLineNumber())
                        .quantity(deliveryDocumentLine.getExpectedQty())
                        .vnpkQty(deliveryDocumentLine.getVnpkQty())
                        .build()));
```

I want to get

```
List<POList>
```

from this right hand expression. Cannot understand how to convert this Stream of stream to a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `flatMap`, it's trivial to convert a `Stream<Stream<POLine>>` to a `Stream<POLine>`:

```
List<POLine> output = 
    list.flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though it might be simpler to produce a `List<POLine>` directly:

```
List<POLine> list = 
    poSearchResponseList.stream()
                        .flatMap(posr -> posr.getDeliveryDocumentLines()
                                             .stream()
                                             .map(dl -> 
                                                 POLine.builder()
                                                       .poLineNumber(dl.getPurchaseReferenceLineNumber())
                                                       .quantity(deliveryDocumentLine.getExpectedQty())
                                                       .vnpkQty(deliveryDocumentLine.getVnpkQty())
                                                       .build()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get a `Stream<Stream<POLine>> list`?? You already have a list of `POLine` from the `poSearchResponseList` instance.

So, I think you have a `List<SearchResponse>` which has a `List<DeliveryDocumentLine>` and from this you want to get a `List<POList>`, right?

If that is the scenario you can use `Stream.flatMap()` method.

#### Why?

Well, it is because this method can produce something like this `Stream<SearchResponse> -> Stream<POList>`

Now, first you extract `SearchResponse` using `.stream()` then you flat it using `Stream.flatMap()` then here you will have a `SearchResponse` object from this object you can extract the data of the lines, like this:

```java
List<POLine> list = poSearchResponseList
        .stream()
        .flatMap(response -> response.getDeliveryDocumentLines()
                .stream()
                .map(item -> POLine.builder()
                        .poLineNumber(item.getPurchaseReferenceLineNumber())
                        .quantity(item.getExpectedQty())
                        .vnpkQty(item.getVnpkQty())
                        .build()
                )
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

To see it in separate steps for better readability we can write it accordingly:

```
        List<POLine> list =
                poSearchResponseList.stream()
                        .map(POLine::getDeliveryDocumentLines)
                        .flatMap(Stream::of)
                        .map(dl ->
                                POLine.builder()
                                        .poLineNumber(dl.getPurchaseReferenceLineNumber())
                                        .quantity(deliveryDocumentLine.getExpectedQty())
                                        .vnpkQty(deliveryDocumentLine.getVnpkQty())
                                        .build())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What it does:

- Creates stream from poSearchResponseList,
- then mapps elements to deliveryDocumentLines, returning: `Stream<List<DeliveryDocumentLine>>`
- reducing List with to stream method to type `Stream<DeliveryDocumentLine>`
- in last step mapping to expected type and collecting to expected collection.